# How to get coordinates of geometry in its own projection?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am calculating the centroid of a Feature, and then extracting the geometry of that point in a specific projection. When I print the geometry, it shows me under coordinates the coordinates I expect. Still, if I am trying to extract the coordinates using `.coordinates()`, it gives a different set of coordinates, presumably in a different projection.

How can I get the coordinates of a geometry in the projection of the geometry, or by explicitly mentioning the projection?

[The code that showcases the issue](https://code.earthengine.google.com/235a7f01bbf68cdb93ed028764d9f895):

```
var random_region = ee.FeatureCollection(
        [ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Polygon(
                [[[-69.06480462117582, -10.919336774192457],
                  [-69.06480462117582, -10.944028822959991],
                  [-69.03313309712797, -10.944028822959991],
                  [-69.03313309712797, -10.919336774192457]]], null, false),
            {
              "system:index": "0"
            })]);
var central_point = ee.Feature(random_region.first()).centroid(1)
var destination_landsat_projection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2").filterBounds(central_point.geometry()).first().projection()
central_point = central_point.geometry(null, destination_landsat_projection)
central_point.aside(print,"Point").coordinates().aside(print,"wrong coordinates")
//Point (494649.22, -1208426.05), EPSG:32619
//wrong [2868.8074992709517,1301.368171039052]
ee.Geometry.Point(ee.List([494649.22, -1208426.05]), 'EPSG:32619').aside(print,"Point").coordinates().aside(print,"correct coordinates")
//Point (494649.22, -1208426.05), EPSG:32619
//correct [494649.22,-1208426.05]
```

Comment: This seems like a Bug to me. At the very least inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: @JonasV To me as well. I posted it already on developer's group, but that's a busy place where threads get easily lost. I just posted this as a bug as well, just in case someone stumbles on this question https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198012628

Comment: You might get lucky and Noel Gorelick sees your question, he's quite active on here. That could speed things up a bit

Comment: @JonasV That's exactly what I was planning on. Meanwhile, I discovered that the unexpected coordinates are some coordinates based directly on Landsat, because 1 unit is 1 pixel. Funnily enough, that's exactly what I needed. My script now depends on this undocumented? feature. Now I hope this won't be fixed too soon, or that it will be fixed with bug to bug backwards compatibility :D

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting. You are right that it is not well documented, but it seems that printing the geometry will give you the point coordinates as
`xOrigin + x*xPixelSize` and `yOrigin+y*yPixelSize`, while the `ee.Geometry.Point.coordinates()` will give you just the `[x,y]` (in the units of the projection).

Here's a code example that demonstrates this in four projections:

```js
// EPSG:4326 with identity transform:
var projA = ee.Projection("EPSG:4326")
projA.evaluate(function(p){
  print("projA crs: ", p.crs)             // EPSG:4326
  print("projA transform: ", p.transform) // [1,0,0,0,1,0]
})
// EPSG:4326 in half-degree units:
var projB = ee.Projection("EPSG:4326", [0.5,0,0,0,0.5,0])
projB.evaluate(function(p){
  print("projB crs: ", p.crs)             // EPSG:4326
  print("projB transform: ", p.transform) // [0.5,0,0,0,0.5,0]
})
// EPSG:32619 with identity transform:
var projC = ee.Projection("EPSG:32619")
projC.evaluate(function(p){
  print("projC crs: ", p.crs)             // EPSG:32619
  print("projC transform: ", p.transform) // [1,0,0,0,1,0]
})
// EPSG:32619 in 30m units, with origin at 1000,-1000
var projD = ee.Projection("EPSG:32619", [30,0,1000,0,-30,-1000])
projD.evaluate(function(p){
  print("projD crs: ", p.crs)             // EPSG:32619
  print("projD transform: ", p.transform) // [30,0,1000,0,-30,-1000]
})
//[xScale, xShearing, xTranslation, yShearing, yScale, yTranslation]
var x = 1, y=1  // The x,y coordinates we will use.
// Point with coordinates [1,1] in different projections:
var pointA = ee.Geometry.Point([x,y], projA).aside(print, "pointA");
var pointB = ee.Geometry.Point([x,y], projB).aside(print, "pointB");
var pointC = ee.Geometry.Point([x,y], projC).aside(print, "pointC");
var pointD = ee.Geometry.Point([x,y], projD).aside(print, "pointD");
// Coordinates given as xOrigin+x*xPixelSize, yOrigin+y*yPixelSize
pointA.evaluate(function(p){print("pointA coordinates: " , p.coordinates)})
pointB.evaluate(function(p){print("pointB coordinates: " , p.coordinates)})
pointC.evaluate(function(p){print("pointC coordinates: " , p.coordinates)})
pointD.evaluate(function(p){print("pointD coordinates: " , p.coordinates)})
// The above prints the same information, as a javascript object 
// i.e. this is what gets printed in the .aside(print) above..

// However, the ee.Geometry.Point.coordinates() has the original
// x,y in the units of the projection, i.e. 1,1, for all points above:
print("Point A coordinates (x,y):", pointA.coordinates())
print("Point B coordinates (x,y):", pointB.coordinates())
print("Point C coordinates (x,y):", pointC.coordinates())
print("Point D coordinates (x,y):", pointD.coordinates())
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/6501555c593bd0c861d545b93584cc22